# Testing for equality in Java

Tags: java, junit

How do you use the equals method in Java? In JUnit I am testing to see if two values that are initialized as equal are the same by asserting that they are, but my test is failing. I made sure to check that the Object being passed in is an instanceof the other object but I'm not sure why my test is failing.

```
@Test
public void testEqualityOnBillSimple()
{
    Date d1 = new Date( 3,4,2020);
    Money m1 = new Money(10);
    Bill b1 = new Bill( m1, d1, "fred");
    Bill b2 = new Bill( m1, d1, "fred");

    assertTrue( b1.equals(b2));
}

public boolean equals (Object toCompare) {
    try {
        if (toCompare instanceof Bill) {
            Bill that = (Bill) toCompare;
            return this.amount.equals(that.amount) && 
            this.dueDate.equals(that.dueDate) && 
           this.paidDate.equals(that.paidDate) && 
            this.originator.equals(that.originator);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: originator is the string that says who the bill is being paid to. in this case, it is Fred

Comment: Did you override the `equals()` method and the `hashcode()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with hashcodes yet

Comment: You caught an `Exception`, swallowed it, and did nothing with it. This is an extremely bad practice, because if there's an error happening there, then you have no idea and it defaults to `#equals` returning false mysteriously.

Comment: I realize that is problematic but does it have an effect on my code now? That was a temporary solution to a bunch of errors/fails in my test suite.

Comment: The thing is, it's not a solution, it's just sweeping the problem under the rug.

Comment: I would recommend using `assertEquals(expected, test)` instead of `assertTrue(v1.equals(v2))`, because you get better error messaging in your test results. Always make the expected value the first parameter so that assertion failure messages read correctly.

Comment: If an exception being thrown would be considered a test failure, remove the try/catch block, adding the exception to the test method signature if necessary to get it to compile.  Any thrown exception will cause it to fail.  If you have test cases where a successful test means an exception is thrown, you can explicitly designate an exception type as the expected result of the test using the @Test(expected=SomeException.class) annotation on the test method

Answer (score 3):

> How do you use the equals method in Java?

You call it!

---

What you really want to know is why your test if failing.  And that boils to how you should *correctly* implement an `equals(Object)`.  In general, the answer is that it depends on the intended semantics of your (entire) object.

Facially, the code you have written is mostly right.  Catching and squashing `Exception` as you have done is bad practice, and probably semantically incorrect.  It *could be* hiding the real cause of your problems; e.g. an unanticipated NPE in one of the field comparisons.

You commented:

> I realize that is problematic but does it have an effect on my code now?

Potentially, yes!

The correct behavior would be for `equals` would probably to allow any unanticipated unchecked exceptions to propagate.  Comparing incomplete `Bill` objects that have missing fields is arguably incorrect.  If the code is intended to cope with that (i.e. `null` fields) then you should use `null` tests to avoid the NPEs.

(I don't think it makes sense to treat a `null` field as causing `equals` to return `false`.  What if you compare a `Bill` with a `null` field against itself, for example.)

To be completely sure that there are no other problems, we would need to see the rest of the implementation of the `Bill` class.

---

Finally, as @a-sir points out, if you override `equals` and you should (technically) override `hashCode` as well.  Bad things will happen if you ever use a `Bill` as a key in a `HashMap` or an element of a `HashSet` ... and the class has incompatible `equals` and `hashCode` methods.